# Reinforcement Learning Reward Function for Optimizing Golf Aim?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I read [this article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227757/where-to-ask-basic-questions-about-machine-learning), mentioning that either here, or StackOverflow would be the best places to ask generic machine learning questions, however, if the question isn't programming specific with a minimal reproducible example, the mod's at S.O. can't wait to shut you down pretty quick, so figured I'd try here first.

I'm developing a small RL environment for a school project that plays a 2D golf game, and I need confirmation that my idea makes sense for a reward function.

To keep things simple, I believe that working with the "distance from the pin" makes the most sense, in that the agent should be able to drain the ball in as few shots as possible. Read that again as "distance from the hole", not "distance TO the hole" as these would be two different calculations.

It's my understanding that to find the quickest path, you should assign negative rewards so that it learns to make decisions to minimize those punishments. With that in mind, I'm thinking that whatever your previous shot's distance from the hole is, the negative value of that would be the reward for that shot.

For example, you're in the tee box with your driver out, and the pin is 400 yards away. You whack the ball straight at the pin for 250 yards. Your reward for that shot would be -150 as you're now 150 yards from the pin. You hit your second shot onto the green where you're now just 10 yards from the pin. Your reward for that shot would be -10. You birdie this par 4 hole, so your putt reward would be 0 (summing to a "reward" of -160 for the hole). Conceptually this should make it so that if the agent hits the ball too far AWAY from the pin on any shot, the reward would be even more negative than it should be, so it should learn to make shots that minimize those punishments.

Am I correct that this would be a good way to implement a simple reward function for the problem of finding the quickest path to the target? I think for golf specifically, one COULD factor in what shot it is, like if it's a par 3 and you sink it on your first shot from the tee box, the reward for that should be greater than the sum of any 2 or 3 or more shot's reward, but we can keep it simple for now.

Comment: I think that it does make sense. Try it, if it doesn't work well, try to modify it a bit, maybe make it quadratic over the distance, etc. Try things until you get a good model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a plausible thing to try.  Give it a try and see how it works.

An even better metric might be some estimate of (the negation of) the expected number of strokes needed, given the remaining distance to the hole.  This is not a purely linear function, so might give a better reward function.